# Inserting extra pages without affecting the rest of the text

Tags: floats, page-breaking, page-numbering

I am working on a document of the two-column `IEEEtran` style and I want to "insert" two special pages.

So I have these two page-filling `figure`s. I want each figure to appear on its own page, say page 2 and 3, and the remaining text to end on page 1 and continue normally on page 4 as if the two extra pages were not there. The figure pages are just inserts which should be numbered correctly, but otherwise should not affect the layout of the remaining text pages.

I do not want to start new pages with `newpage` and `clearpage`, because that would leave empty space before the two extra pages. Rather, I want text to "flow around" them.

This is a general question, so please excuse if I do not post a code example, because I do not think the actual code is very relevant here.

Comment: Do you want the extra pages to be numbered as "normal" pages in the document? Or should the fourth page be numbered "2" as if the extra pages were not there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like the following work for you?

(I am not sure whether you want this, since you say,  *continue normally on page 4 as if the two extra pages were not there.* Do this mean that these will not increase the page number? If that is the case, my answer is incorrect and I will delete this.)

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{First Last}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[!p]
  \centering
  \lipsum[30-35]
  \caption{First full page figure.}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[!p]
  \centering
  \lipsum[40-45]
  \caption{Second full page figure.}
  \label{fig:second}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[21-30]

\lipsum[51-60]

\end{document}
```